# User cards (?) seem broken for users with many badges

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design

User cards (not sure what official SE name is) seem to be too small for fitting the info for users with many badges.

2 examples in 1 image:

[image]

This seems invariant as far as zooming in/out with Ctrl-wheelscroll

Firefox 26, didn't try other browsers.

**Edit by Izkata** - This is what I see in Firefox 21 on Ubuntu:

[image]

This problem also seems to occur on Chrome.

[image]

Comment: You got it - User Card is its official name. :) See [this help article](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) under the heading "Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings."

Comment: I see the same thing here, Firefox 26, Windows 8.1.

Comment: They share some CSS, but fixing the badge page might not automatically fix the question and answer infoboxes, depending on the desired fix (right now it's fixed-width and assumes a limited number of badges).  [DavRob60 is another good example](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10200/2242), since he has 50 gold badges it's pushed even further off

Comment: The problem is clear. That member obviously has too many badges.

Comment: I don't have this problem on my card :'(

Comment: It would be better to post this on MSE (though I'd expect it already is there.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in the recent CSS updates around the user flair box

From [How did the Master escape from the Eye of Harmony?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76194/how-did-the-master-escape-from-the-eye-of-harmony/76196#76196):

[image]

From [What was the benefit of the belts given by Galadriel to 3 Fellowship members?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109909/what-was-the-benefit-of-the-belts-given-by-galadriel-to-3-fellowship-members):

[image]

Chrome 47, Windows 8.1